# linux run ffmpeg within c++ code

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg, stdin, sdi

the O.S. is Linux.
I have an old c++ code that writes raw SDI input from a capture device to a file.
My intent is to modify this program and redirect the raw video from the SDI source to the stdin of ffmpeg.
How can I do that?
Is better to run ffmpeg within the c++ source code (how can I do that?)?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Open a pipe, start mencoder and configure it to read from the pipe. Then write data to the pipe.

If you want to use a library, write a code (etc), then take a look into [libav](http://libav.org/)

Comment: libavcodec has long since been renamed to libav, and is the core library of the ffmpeg project.

Comment: @greyfade: I think libav is a recent fork. You have both libav.org and ffmpeg.org now :)

Comment: I can not use library because I have to use an old version of ffmpeg that support vhook. So I will try a pipe, hoping that ffmpeg is able to recognise the data that I put it inside.

Answer (score 0):

I use a C++ wrapper around FFMpeg called [FOBS](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/)

my2c